# In Mongoose, how to limit find, update, delete to first 100 documents in the collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

A simplify situation is this:
There are 1000+ documents in the MongoDb collection, certain user(e.g. free account) can only operate on the first 100 documents.

The operation includes: find, update, and delete.

How to limit operation to first 100 documents in a collection? I have the following algorithem in mind:

```
1) find the first 100 documents
2) do find, update, delete, paginate only for this sub set of documents.
```

How to achieve this? If possible, please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep some numeric id field in your collection

In this way you can easily filter out your first n customers and you will not have to search records first and then process it according to your need.

### Find a customer having first name as 'John'

```
Modal.find({
    id: {
        $gte: 1,
        $lte: 100
    },
    first_name: 'John'
}
)
```

### delete a customer which has first name as 'John'

```
Modal.deleteOne({
    id: {
        $gte: 1,
        $lte: 100
    },
    first_name: "John"
}
)
```

### Paginate by 10 doc per Page

```
Modal.find({
    id: {
        $gte: 1,
        $lte: 100
    }
}
).limit(10).skip(10)
```

Comment: I see... In this case, I need to add another key...  it gives me a lot of inspiration. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Correct. Glad that it was helpful in some way :)